# Generic class with two generic types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic class for "Selectable Items" which is useful for Lists. Now I want a selectable item to include a list of other selectable items. Here is my code:

```
public interface ISelectableItem<T>
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem<T>> SubItems { get; }
}
```

For now the `SubItems` collection is of the same type as the SelectableItem itself.

Question is: how do I have to declare this interface so that `SubItems` is also `ISelectableItem`, but of type `T2`, not `T`?

Answer (score 3):

Add a second generic type, `T2`, to the type definition:

```
public interface ISelectableItem<T, T2>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem<T2>> SubItems { get; }
}
```

Plan B would be to deviate between the sub items and master items by adding a second interface layer:

```
public interface ISelectableItem<T, T2> : ISelectableItem<T>
{
    ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem<T2>> SubItems { get; }
}

public interface ISelectableItem<T>
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This would work for example:

```
public class A : ISelectableItem<string> { ... }

public class B : ISelectableItem<string, string> { ... }

B b = new B();
b.SubItems.Add(new A());
```

Or even:

```
b.SubItems.Add(new B());
```

Comment: If you add a second generic type T2, then "ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem<...>>" also expects two generic types. So this is not working.

Comment: @okieh: Okay. What about this then?